# Power Shell Command Output not displayed in ASP.net Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I create ASP.net webform application using MS VS 2015. According to code, I install System.Management.Automation library from NuGet packages. And I'm trying to display my PowerShell command output in asp textbox. After click on ExecuteCode button, Code not showing error. but output not showing. page showing loading symbol in top corner of tab continuously. PowerShell command works at PowerShell console IDE as well. I hope you solutions for that.

My PowerShell Command as:

```
 mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.8.184 -p 1883 -t "topic"
```

[image: UI]

My .aspx code :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="FFAS.WebForm2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><h1 align="left">PowerShell Command Harness</h1></td></tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>PowerShell Command</td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <br />
                </td><td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Input" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="433px" Height="73px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                &nbsp;</td><td>
                <asp:Button ID="ExecuteCode" runat="server" Text="Execute" Width="200" onclick="ExecuteCode_Click" />
            </td></tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><h3>Result</h3></td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                    &nbsp;</td><td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ResultBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="700" Height="200" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My aspx.cs Code as:

```
protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clean the Result TextBox
    ResultBox.Text = string.Empty;

    // Initialize PowerShell engine
    var shell = PowerShell.Create();

    // Add the script to the PowerShell object
    shell.Commands.AddScript(Input.Text);

    // Execute the script
    var results = shell.Invoke();

    // display results, with BaseObject converted to string
    // Note : use |out-string for console-like output
    if (results.Count > 0)
    {
        // We use a string builder ton create our result text
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var psObject in results)
        {
            // Convert the Base Object to a string and append it to the string builder.
            // Add \r\n for line breaks
            builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }

        // Encode the string in HTML (prevent security issue with 'dangerous' caracters like < >
        ResultBox.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.8.184 -p 1883 -t "topic"` do/return when you run it directly from powershell?  Also, what happens if you use a more predictable command as your input like `$env:computername` or `dir c:\`?

Comment: thank you for your response. this command return IOT sensor device data through mqtt service. when directly run the code in power shell, successfully return.

Comment: According to this [page](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto_pub-sub-clients/) "When you start this client it runs indefinitely until stopped using CTRL+C.".  `shell.Invoke()` is likely blocking here since the client would be running and not completing.  If you are looking to keep this client running and get responses back from it you may want to look at using `BeginInvoke(inputObject, outputObject)` and `EndInvoke()`.  Check `ExecuteAsynchronously()` on this page http://cbprasad.blogspot.com/2015/10/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.html

Comment: this time output record line update with line by line to lower in every 5 second. want to display that. I'm struggling in the code now. can you modify the my code to new one?

Comment: Have you inserted any breakpoints when executing? It would be interesting to know what the *building* variable holds right when it's assigning *ResultBox.Text*

Comment: Also, *Input.Text* is not even declared within the *ExecuteCode_Click* action, it should be *e.Text*. Either way your not passing any variables from the form on the click action.